# SSIS - Loading Excel removes Percentage Symbol

Tags: .net, sql, excel, ssis

I'm loading some Excel data to Database through SSIS. When the data is loaded, the SSIS ignores the % symbol in the worksheet.

For example:

```
Col1    Col2    Col3    Col4
----------------------------
98.7%   76.2%   3.09    23%
```

In the above case, I need to find the columns which have % (to distinguish between numbers and percentages) but SSIS reads the data as 0.9868998899, 0.75478490944, 0.03688899973, 0.230000

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: are the columns dynamic? Because if they are, then you will need a vb script to make the source dynamic.

Comment: may be a duplicate of [SSIS the Percentage column from Excel -> SQL Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8162612/ssis-the-percentage-column-from-excel-sql-server)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because the `%` symbol in Excel is probably part of the formatting and not the data.

If you want to make the `%` symbol part of the data (which will stop the fields being numeric, incidentally) then you'll need to transform it either using ***Paste Special*** or a formula to concatenate the `%` symbol:

```
=A1&"%"
```

Probably better for you is to keep the data numeric until *after* it arrives in SSIS, then reformat it in the destination. That way, you'll avoid rounding errors and other conversion nasties.